# Windows application icon not apear in the explorer

Tags: qt

I think I did follow all the step guided [here.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/appicon.html) I guess res file has linked with the `exe` because the file size has increased.

My .pro file (vaastu.pro)

```
QT       += sql core gui printsupport

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = vaastu
TEMPLATE = app


win32 {
   RC_FILE = vaastu.rc
}
SOURCES += ...

HEADERS  += ....

FORMS    += ...

RESOURCES += \
    Fonts.qrc
```

My .rc file (vaastu.rc)

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE      "vaastu.ico"
```

What is the reason for this? What am I doing wrong? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .rc file:

```
#include "resource.h"
```

In resource.h file:

```
#define IDI_ICON1  1
```

Comment: I'm getting this error after suggested changes.
vaastu.rc:3: error: RC2135 : file not found: IDI_ICON1

Comment: I dig the exe with Resource Hacker, resource files are inside it but I couldn't find Icon_Group section.

Comment: Finally got it work. Thank you. And previous Error was something strange. Found a solution to that error from here(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/2f5ce42f-0547-4ad9-868f-49df5ecbc858/) I did create new RC file with (Unicode encoding) and your solution worked.

Comment: Please update your answer to IDI_ICON to IDI_ICON1 to avoid confuse who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the location of your icon "vaastu.ico". It should be same as your source code location.

```
<source root>
   |--> vaastu.ico
   |--> vaastu.rc
   |--> vaastu.pro
   |--> <other folders/files>
```

Comment: yes. It's inside source directory. And it's linking without error. I dig the exe with Resource Hacker, resource files are inside it.

Comment: I included the app icon with my other icons inside a resource file 'icon.qrc', and of course I also initialized the resource file. I'm not sure if this tells the QtCreator to do some 'magic' work.

Comment: I did try not worked out.Creating new RC file with Unicode encoding and @Dmitry solution together worked. Anyway thank for help :)